# Why is my json.loads() call improperly formatting strings?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am building a custom responder for the Cortex/Hive, and I have been unable to get my request response to properly convert into a JSON format. When testing in the local development environment, my code in getCount function works flawlessly, but when adding the cortex responder wrapper to it, my code fails.

Since the responder runs from Cortex, I do not receive an error message beyond "input: null", so I had to write to an error log. Using this log, I determined that the error stems from the line `data = json.loads(response.text)`. I tried using simple json, regex-ing the desired value from response.text, changing encoding methods, and banging my head on the keyboard from the sheer stupidity of it not working.

CODE:

```
import requests

import json

from cortexutils.responder import Responder

class Search(Responder):
        def __init__(self):
                # Debug
                with open('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/error.log','a') as error_log:
                        error_log.write('Starting: \n')
                        error_log.write('\n\n')
                # End Debug

                Responder.__init__(self)
                self.apiuser = self.get_param('config.api_user', None)
                self.apikey = self.get_param('config.api_key', None)
                self.url = self.get_param('config.api_url', None)
                self.ioc_type = self.get_param('data.dataType', None)
                self.ioc = self.get_param('data.data', None)
                # Debug
                with open('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/error.log','a') as error_log:
                        error_log.write('User ID: \n')
                        error_log.write(self.apiuser)
                        error_log.write('\n\nSecret: \n')
                        error_log.write(self.apikey)
                        error_log.write('\n\n')
                        error_log.write('IOC Type: \n')
                        error_log.write(self.ioc_type)
                        error_log.write('\n\n')
                        error_log.write('Value: \n')
                        error_log.write(self.ioc)
                        error_log.write('\n\n')
                # End Debug

        def getCount(self):
                with open('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/error.log','a') as error_log:
                        error_log.write('Starting Count: \n')
                        error_log.write('\n\n')

                url = self.url

                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

                params={'type': self.ioc_type, 'value': self.ioc}

                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params = params, auth=(self.apiuser, self.apikey))

                data = json.loads(response.text)
                with open('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/error.log','a') as error_log:
                        error_log.write('Response: ')
                        error_log.write(data)

                deviceCount = data['resources'][0]['device_count']

                self.count = deviceCount



        def run(self):
                Responder.run(self)

                self.getCount()

                self.operations()

        def operations(self):
                return [self.build_operation('AddTagToCase', tag= self.count)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Search().run()


Results from response.text:
 {"meta":{"query_time":0.014920091,"trace_id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"},
"resources":[{"id":"sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"type":"sha256",
"value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"device_count":11}],"errors":[]}

Error Logging results:

Starting:


User ID:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Secret:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

IOC Type:
sha256

Value:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

run starting:
Starting Count:
```

self.count should be equal to device_count, but json.loads fails to format this response. This can be seen in my error log results where Count() starts but abruptly ends before data is written to it.

If you could please provide insight into why this fails to format the response properly, please shed some light.

Thank you

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. As a new user, also visit [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a sample `response.text` value?

Comment: "null input" and "empty variable" don't mean anything in particular in Python. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt

I included a scrubbed sample response

Comment: @JohnGordon I included a scrubbed sample response

Comment: " json.loads fails to format this response" - what does this mean?  Do you get an error?  What is the eventual value of `self.count`

Comment: @snakecharmerb as stated in my post, I do not get an error since the program is run through the Cortex/ The Hive. This means that the request response is not being formatted into a JSON format. Value of self.count should equal output of "device_count" which can be seen in the sample response provided

Comment: Given that sample json data, `self.count` should be set to 11.  Are you getting the error with __this__ json specifically? When the error happens, what exact value does `self.count` have?  Is it `None`, or an empty string, or something else?

Comment: @JohnGordon it is not just this specific json; it occurs regardless what my inputs are. I have tried to output `self.count` to my error log, but the log stops as soon as I attempt to append the `data` variable. I assume that this means that the variable is null but am not 100% confident

Comment: Your log shouldn't just stop.  Can you show us the logging statements?

Comment: @JohnGordon included statements that capture for log as well as logging results in code block

Comment: You aren't writing `self.count` to the log...

Comment: @JohnGordon yes i know that... I stated that i attempted to log it, but since my log does not get past the line where i initialize the data variable, i left that piece of code out intentionally..

Comment: If you have code that's not working, we need to see that code exactly as it is, so we can figure out _why_ it isn't working.  If you just leave the code out, we have no way to figure out the problem.

Comment: Again, extract a [mcve] and please pay attention to the "M" and "V" parts. The code is supposed to be executable by anyone here in order to reproduce the problem. Note that this example does not have to do anything other than being an example, so e.g. consider hard-coding the response string you get. Also, your question should state the expected and actual outcome clearly, your formatting doesn't make it clear at all.

Comment: @JohnGordon i can assure you that the inclusion/exclusion of that snippet of code is irrelevant; the result of the program does not change based on its inclusion

Answer (score 0):

This is my standard way of getting a json response from an API using the requests module

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, auth=(self.apiuser, self.apikey)).json()
```

Comment: I tried that method to no success. I included a sample response that may be able to give more insight to the issue

Comment: could you log the result of response.status_code, response.encoding, response.text, and catch exceptions in the json.loads() statement?